# Is there any function to check when the file was uploaded to database in php

Tags: php

I have a file which i am uploading in database. I want to know the timing of the upload. i am not doing any modification in my file. Its just i want to know the timing at which my file was uploaded to database. So, filectime, filemtime, and fileatime is not giving me correct output.

Comment: Why don't you just store the information along with the file?

Comment: You should store this along with the file, but retrospectively the best thing you can do is check the file modified time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files can not upload to database, they just moves to your filesystem. And then you may want to add timestamp while saving the file path to your database

-first create uploaded_at column to your table.

-upload the file and move it to selected path

-create timestamp

```
$date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
```

and save the `$date` to your table with image path